# Will vs want - can they be used interchangeably?

Tags: grammar, verbs, sentence, phrasing

Here are two sentences that sort of mean the same thing, but need your help in identifying which one would be more appropriate.

I do already have an idea as to which phrase would be more appropriate but I still chose to go with the other one.

> His mind pushed back, but he kept **willing** it to do all that it still could.
>
> His mind pushed back, but he kept **wanting** it to do all that it still could.

Does using 'wanting' instead of 'willing' drastically change the meaning here?

Since will is more of a statement of commitment, 'willing' might seem more appropriate here. But in some cases using want in its place doesn't change the meaning.

Comment: I think we need some more context. Is this some kind of parapsychological battle, or is this some more conventional scenario?

Comment: So to elaborate, it's basically a situation where a person is trying to solve a puzzle that requires a lot of mental exertion. At one one point this person starts to feel mentally exhausted, but they keep pushing their mind to work on the problem. I hope this makes the context clear.

Comment: You should really edit the question to include the context in it — it's not true that everybody here always reads the comments. And I'd use *his* *mind* rather than *the mind* — some languages, like French, prefer to use the definite article in these situations, but English strongly prefers the possessive.

Comment: Since you use *pushing*, that meaning calls for "willing". "Wanting" is just a desire without that forced quality.

Comment: @PeterShor thanks for pointing that out. I understand the ambiguity it can create. Will make the edit.

Comment: @YosefBaskin thanks. 'without that forced quality' is a nice way to put it. 'Kept willing' does make things more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *want* something to happen, you wish it would.

If you *will* something to happen, you try to 'make' it happen by your own mental efforts.

**Will** (verb). 1. Make or try to make (someone) do something or (something) happen by the exercise of mental powers.
"reluctantly he willed himself to turn and go back" (Oxford Languages)

Comment: Thanks kate. This helps. So in a way it can be said that while both the sentences can get the idea across, the one that uses 'kept willing' is a little more specific. As yosef also pointed in his comment - 'wanting is a desire without that forced quality'. But people would still be able to understand the meaning behind the line even if I use 'kept wanting'. Right?

Comment: Yes, of course, because, as I said, _wanting it to..._ means _wishing it would..._

Comment: No, @ShubhamKumar, I would not say that both sentences communicate the same idea.  "Willing" in this context is active, whereas "wanting" is passive.  They are related, but not interchangeable.  I'm not sure which you actually intend, but one is not a good substitute for the other.  In some other contexts, however, "will" and "want" are closer to each other.

Answer (score 2):

*Will* already means *want* in English. That's the deontic sense of *will*; its epistemic sense of 'expected future' is what's often called "the future tense". But like all modal auxiliary verbs, *will* has several senses. The deontic sense of *will* as 'want to, be willing to' can be found in *if*-clauses, where the epistemic sense of *will* is not allowed, but the deontic is OK:

- **If he will come today, it's OK* (ungrammatical epistemic: should use *comes*)
- *If he'll sign the documents, it's OK* (grammatical deontic = 'if he is willing to sign')

In German, where modal auxiliaries are inflected and have infinitives and participles, they are not used to represent the future like *will* is. German uses the verb *werden* 'become' for its future construction. The German modal auxiliary that's cognate to English *will* (both come from the same prehistoric root) is ***wollen***, which simply means 'want'. So *Ich will gehen* doesn't mean 'I will go' but rather 'I wanna go'; the way you'd say 'I will go' is *Ich werde gehen*.

There is also a verb *will* which refers to magical, theological, political, or mystical results achieved by mental (or magical, theological, political, or mystical) means. You see this in the reports of the First Crusade in 1096 CE, with the slogan *Deus le veult*, or 'God wills it'. The present participle of this inflected verb *will*, *willing*, is often used in constructions like *be willing to `VP`* referring to potential agreement.

So, to answer the question, there are **some** occasions where *will* and *want* can both occur in the same place without much difference in meaning. But not usually, because they're different types of verbs and follow different grammar rules -- the modal *will* hasta be followed by an infinitive, for instance, but the verb *want* doesn't; and *want* has tensed and participial verb forms, whereas *will* doesn't.

Comment: Causative 'will' corresponds to the idea of mind-over-matter in the 'super/supranatural control' sense ('willed him to miss the penalty'). But 'be willing to' involves self control, whether at the keen-to-comply or acquiescent level. Can inflectable 'will [[to]' also be classed separately with the additional 'desire strongly [to]' sense?